# python based IP address calculator (IPCALC) code

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

I've the python CGI for user entered input for IP address calculation but python ipcalc is not taking input as a variable, for example I'm trying to run this code

```
>>> import ipcalc
>>> ip='10.84.35.11'
>>> mask=24
>>> print ip
    10.84.35.11
>>> print mask
   24
>>> subnet = ipcalc.Network(ip/mask)
```

It gives me an error-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

where as if I pass the value as it is like subnet = ipcalc.Network('10.84.35.11/24') it works perfect!

I'm new to programming, can someone help to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a string representing a network:

```
subnet = ipcalc.Network("%s/%d" % (ip, mask))
```

Right now you're trying to use the `/` operator on `str` and `int` which is not defined (as the error says).